# Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99 - Python embedded

Tags: python, ios, llvm-clang, .a

I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/albertz/python-embedded) in my iOS app. I got it compiling properly, but when I try to run the following I get an error.

#### Code

```
#import "pyconfig.h"
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Py_SetProgramName((char*)[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] UTF8String]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 'Hello world!'");
}
```

#### Error

```
Error: Implicit declaration of function 'Py_SetProgramName' is invalid in C99
Warning: This function declaration is not a prototype
```

---

```
Error: Implicit declaration of function 'Py_Initialize' is invalid in C99
Warning: This function declaration is not a prototype
```

---

```
Error: Implicit declaration of function 'PyRun_SimpleString' is invalid in C99
Warning: This function declaration is not a prototype
```

I have linked `libpython.a` and have added `pylib`. I am using Xcode 9.2

Comment: You  should `#include <Python.h>` to get the prototypes for the Python functions. Do you do that?

Comment: It says that `'Python.h' file not found`. I do have `#import "pyconfig.h"`

Comment: What have you installed? How did you install `libpython.a`?

Comment: I ran `compile.py` from the linked repo. Then I dragged `libpython.a` and `pylib` into Xcode.

Comment: The project seems to include a version of CPython. In that project there is an `Include` folder, containing `Python.h`. This file you need. Is that available in your system?

Comment: After adding the `Include` folder it got rid of the previous errors, but now I am getting this error: `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64`. Thanks for the help!